# Syntax error in jQuery import (AngularJS)

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am getting an error saying that the imported version of jQuery I am using contains a syntax error. It is the only imported library with this issue - including AngularJS and Bootstrap (which are working fine). I do need jQuery because the bootstrap instance depends on it - and it is something I intend to use.

`Plunker` showing the issue. Open the console and refresh the `plunker` to see the issue.
http://plnkr.co/edit/W0x9kpN3xj1QGtoFXMGk?p=preview

This is strange and I haven't seen it before. The error is outlined below.

```
SyntaxError: Syntax error
   at window.execScript (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js:339:5)
   at globalEval (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js:338:6)
   at converters.text script (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js:9766:4)
   at ajaxConvert (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js:8838:7)
   at done (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js:9259:4)
   at callback (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js:9713:8)
   at send (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js:9719:7)
   at ajax (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js:9210:5)
   at jQuery._evalUrl (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js:9368:2)
   at domManip (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js:5977:10) <div class="ng-scope" ng-view="">
```

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="main.ctrl.js"></script>
    <script src="map.dir.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
      }
    </style>    
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>Map Viewer</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I should also add that I have tried using multiple versions of jQuery and that it is the only library which is providing me with issues.

Comment: You are getting a stone cold SyntaxError. Your IDE will probably highlight it in the code for you. Don't look for the error in your jQuery, it probably resides in your custom code. app.js, main.ctrl.js or map.dir.js.

Furthermore, don't use any minified files when debugging, you get much clearer errors when you use angular.js and angular-route.js.

Also... JS is a async language. Since you are using a not minified version of jquery and minified version of Angular... Chances are that jQuery isn't loaded yet when calling functions that depend on it. (Try looking at require.js)

Comment: Can you reproduce the same in `plunker` or `jfiddle`?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/W0x9kpN3xj1QGtoFXMGk?p=preview

Comment: @stevenca please see the `plunker`. I cannot see a syntax error in my code. If I remove the jQuery and bootstrap I have no errors (bootstrap required jQuery). Functionally the code works fine but I need bootstrap to format it properly. Try clicking on the map to see what I mean.

Comment: `<script src="style.css"></script>` < this (in main.html)

Comment: @Yoshi care to elaborate? I am not using style.css it is a default `plunker` file

Comment: That's a line in your plunker. `styles.css` does not contain valid javascript, and thus you get a syntax error. Or said differently: you're loading a stylesheet using a script tag.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @Yoshi. Something so stupid I completely overlooked

Answer (score 0):

I had an ill-formatted CSS reference in my main.html file (hidden away from me...) which was causing the Syntax Error.